# Is this an answer to the popular FizzBuzz prompt? (eloquentjavascript.net 2.2FizzBuzz)

Tags: javascript, eloquent, fizzbuzz

I am working on this prompt from the book Eloquent Javascript:

> Write a program that uses console.log to print all the >numbers from 1 to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print >"Fizz" instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print >"Buzz" instead. When you have that working, modify your program to print >"FizzBuzz", for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (and still print >"Fizz" or "Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those).

Although my answer shows the same output as the `solution` on `EloquentJavaScript.net`, my code looks a lot different. Is this a correct answer or are there any reasons I should be aware of that would cause problems in my program.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) console.log("FizzBuzz");
    else if (i % 3 == 0) console.log("Fizz");
    else if (i % 5 == 0) console.log("Buzz");
    else console.log(i);
}
```

The author answers the prompt like this:

```
The author answers the prompt like this:

for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
  var output = "";
  if (n % 3 == 0)
    output += "Fizz";
  if (n % 5 == 0)
    output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || n);
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is correct. Not all code that does the same thing will look alike. I think your code is clear, and can think of no useful modification.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered by knowing the requirements of the program. It looks correct indeed, but a good problem statement is needed. In general, the better the *requirements* are, the easier it is to verify if a solution is correct. In real life, verification of code is often done using well-defined test cases, manual or automated.

For example, a requirement could look like this:

> The program should print all integers from 1 to 100, inclusive. If an integer is divisible with three, "Fizz" should be printed instead of the integer. If an integer is divisible with five, "Buzz" should be printed instead of the integer. If an integer is divisible with both three and five, "FizzBuzz" should be printed instead of the integer. Printing should be done to the console output, and each integer should be printed on a new line.

With such a problem description (which I'm sure it's similar to what you had) it's easy to verify the function of the program. Other requirements such as efficiency and coding style might be present, but then we'd have to know these too in order to provide an answer to your question!

Comment: This is the prompt: 

Write a program that uses console.log to print all the numbers from 1 to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print "Buzz" instead.

When you have that working, modify your program to print "FizzBuzz", for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (and still print "Fizz" or "Buzz" for numbers divisible by only one of those).

Comment: @trccodes then it seems just fine. My point was to introduce the concepts of well-defined requirements as a tool for answering questions like "is my code correct" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if( i % 3 ) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if ( i % 5) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log ("FizzBuzz")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a protip: it's generally better on Stack Overflow to _explain_ your answers rather than just posting code that solves the problem.